# Facing issue while uploading a video to server. Requirement is upload binary formate and mp4 type files

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am facing an issue while uploading videos in binary formate and mp4 type files. I implemented below functionalities for uploading videos. But I got response status like 415 and 500 reports. Actually this is the first time I upload a mediatype file please give me any suggestions and other links.facing issue while uploading video in binary formate and mp4 type files.

```
  -(void)camerabuttonHandlerqas{ 

UIAlertController * picker = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Pick an image using" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; 
imagePicker.delegate = self;



UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) { }];

UIAlertAction* takeVideo = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TakeVideo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

imagePicker.view.tag = 100; 

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]; }];
[picker addAction:picture];

[picker addAction:cancel];

picker.view.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test_%d.mp4", [paths objectAtIndex:0],arc4random_uniform(1000)];

NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];


[self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)


{



switch (exportSession.status) {
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
         NSLog(@"status failed");
         break;
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{
         NSLog(@"status success %@ ",videoPath);
         NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary new];

         videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


         [data setObject:[self generatePostDataForData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath]] forKey:@"SelectedvideoURL"];
         imagePickerIsSelected = YES;
         [self postData:data];
         break;

     }

}];


[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData


{    // Generate the post header:

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[file]\"; 

filename=\"somefile\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // Get the post header int ASCII format:


NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Generate the mutable data variable:


NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: [postHeaderData length] ];
[postData setData:postHeaderData];


// Add the image:
// Add the closing boundry:





[postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

// Return the post data:

return postData;
}







-(void) postData:(NSData *)data

{ 


service = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1.1.1.1:8080/testing/postapi/photoUpload/uploadVideo?videoName=video_%d&type=mp4",arc4random_uniform(1000)]

delegate = delegateInstance;
service = [service stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];




NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:service]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];


[request setTimeoutInterval:60];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header

[request setValue:@"mp4/MOV" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];



NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add image data


if (videoData) {
    [body appendData:videoData];
}

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust


[request setHTTPBody:videoData];


// set URL

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                            if (error) {
                                                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                            } else {
                                                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);


} }]; [dataTask resume]; }
```